# Why would a post request in symfony recognized as GET

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am trying to post form data to `/cart/order/edit/` but it doesn't seem to work, more interesting it's working locally but not live.

**Response says**

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>   The server returned a "0 No route found for "GET /cart/order/edit/": Method Not Allowed  (Allow: POST)".

**Routing looks like** 
(php app/console router:debug)

```
cart_order                        GET    /cart/order/
cart_order_edit                   POST   /cart/order/edit/
cart_order_save                   POST   /cart/order/save
```

Here is routing.yml

```
#
# All routes are set up in controller source files in src/*Bundle/Controller/*Controller.php
# using annotations.
#

# Set up Bundle
CartBundle:
    resource: "@CartBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

**Request header in browser says**

> POST /cart/order/edit/ HTTP/1.1

I tried to find some sense but there is none

Here is form i am posting:

```
<form  action="/../cart/order/edit/" method="POST" id="orderForm">
```

Routing in Controller:

```
 * @Route
 * (
 *    "/cart/order/edit/",
 *    name="cart_order_edit"
 * )
 *
 * @Method({"POST"})
```

Comment: What is the code for whatever page is doing the POSTing?

Comment: you really need to include those critical info like your routing yml with the code you are sending the request

Comment: The problem is, Why it works locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to GET an action who is only configured for POST request

did you use a thing like this ?

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/**
 * @Route("/blog")
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/edit/{id}")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I accept your answer, it resolved the issue but still don't know why I cant use POST.

Comment: when you try to access with your web browser to /edit/{id} the default method is GET. your error message say The server returned a "0 No route found for "GET /cart/order/edit/": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)". That means you try to GET a route who only accept POST. check you header request.

Comment: I updated my question with form I am posting and request header which says its POST, and have posted variable :?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly what's wrong when you haven't supplied any code for reference. However, you must check the following:

**routing.yml**
How does your routing.yml file look? It should be something similar to this:

```
route_needed:
    pattern: /cart/order/edit/
    defaults: { _controller: CartBundle:Default:edit }
    requirements:
          _method: POST
```

**Your Form**
How does your form look? It should be something similar to this:

```
<form action="{{ path('route_needed' }}" method="post" {{form_enctype(edit)}}>
****whatever is in your form****
{{form_rest(edit)}}
</form>
```

But, again, we don't know exactly what the problem is because you haven't provided any code. But the examples above come from a working Symfony2 project of mine.

Comment: But I don't wanna force only POST

Comment: You need to define whether you POST or GET.

Comment: Yes I did that in controller 
@Method({"POST"})

Comment: But you must define it in your routing.yml file as well, like I stated above. It's the routing.yml that takes care of URL's etc for Symfony, and it's the routing.yml missing the POST declaration that's giving you this error. It doesn't matter if you have it in your controller or not.

Comment: Are you sure? I have many controllers/actions and all works fine except this?

Comment: Positive. I've never done it any other way, and I've never experienced the problem you have. All I understand is that the routing.yml file handles URL requests and whether they're POST or GET. Trying it won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case was .htaccess redirecting my request.
I sent post and it redirects as get.
Maybe check your htaccess or server conf.